# Reusing data in python

Tags: python, numpy

Im tring to pull data once from Mysql into "c."
Then create an NUMPY array and a dict from the data. 
It seems that once I zip 'c' it no longer stay in orig form. 
Can this be done?

```
import csv, pyodbc#, 
from numpy import *
import numpy as np


csr = cxn.cursor()
c = csr.execute("Select * from p.s")
s = zip(*c)
data = s[0]

for each in data:
    v= dict((each, []) for each in data)
print v

d=[]
for each in c:
    d.append(each)

a = asarray(d)
print a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few more comments:

1. This code

   ```
   for each in data:
       v= dict((each, []) for each in data)
   print v
   ```

   creates the same dictionary over and over again.  You can simply drop the outer for-loop and will get the same result.
2. The part

   ```
   d=[]
   for each in c:
       d.append(each)
   ```

   is equivalent to

   ```
   d = list(c)
   ```
3. Your whole code can be written as

   ```
   csr = cxn.cursor()
   c = csr.execute("Select * from p.s")
   a = numpy.fromiter(c)
   v = dict((key, []) for key in a[:,0])
   ```

Comment: asarray(d) =>>> asarray(d, dtype='object'), will this work with np.fromiter(c)?

Answer (score 2):

`zip(*c)` uses up the `c` iterator so you need to recreate it later by rerunning `c = csr.execute("Select * from p.s")`
 or save its contents before `zip` like `c = list(c)`